# rx-java2 Schedulers.io() steel invokes method from mainThread

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm trying to retrieve data from database using **room** with Rx way.
This is how I'm trying to do that

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    disposable.add(presenter.getAllBooks()
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe({
                 println(it.size())
              }))
}
```

this is `getAllBooks()` method inside presenter

```
fun getAllBooks() : Flowable<List<Book>> {
    val isMainThread = Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()
    if (!isMainThread) {
        updateBooks()
        return db.bookDao().allBooks
    }
    return Flowable.empty()
}
```

Here `isMainThread` variable is always `true`,
I have also tried `observeOn(Shcedulers.io())`, but same problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion, You should try using LiveData. It's similar to rx java but its lifecycle aware and the coolest thing is room supports it

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll use it, but can u tell me what is happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding with RxJava. `getAllBooks` executes its content before RxJava gets into the picture.

```
fun method() : Flowable<String> {
   println("method()")
   return Flowable.just("hello")
}

println("Preparing...")
val f = method();
println("Subscribing...")
f.subscribe({ println(it) })
```

It will print

```
Preparing...
method()
Subscribing...
hello
```

You have to wrap your action into a `Flowable` to make it happen when a subscription happens:

```
disposable.add(
    Flowable.defer(() -> presenter.getAllBooks())  // <----------------------
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
               println(it.size())
            })
)
```

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili Of course, you can also do `defer` _inside_ `getAllBooks()`.